# Изменение документа в mongodb по времени

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, индексы

В MongoDB можно создать индекс для удаления документа по времени (TTL). Имеется ли подобные средства для обновления документа. Либо его создание. Задача состоит в том что бы после определенного времени после создания документа обновить в ней некоторые поля. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эту задачу в реляционных базах данных решают триггеры. В MongoDB подобного функционала нет.

Есть так называемые [**Tailable Cursors**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/) с помощью которых можно подобный функционал создать.

Некоторые реализации на JavaScript:

- https://github.com/afharo/mongo-trigger
- https://github.com/iddogino/mongoTriggers (без tailable cursors, но идея та же)